# Retrieve user data from Google Analytics based on the __utma cookie

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, user-tracking

I am trying to find out how active are the users of my web page after registration, based on what was the source/landing page of their first visit. I would rather not try to track users myself - I am already employing Google Analytics on my web page and I know it uses the __utma cookie to tell one user from another. I can see summarized landing pages/sources in my Analytics reports but would need to have this data per specific user in the time of their sign up.

Essentially, when the user signs up with my web page I would like to retrieve their landing page and source from Google Analytics and store it in my application's database along with user's name, password, activity etc. This way I could check later, for example whether users who came from Google were more prone to buying premium service that those who came from Facebook etc.

I checked the Google Analytics API reference but it doesn't seem to provide getters for this specific data. I've been looking in up in Google and in Stack Overflow for a while.

This seems like a pretty useful functionality, which many websites should need. What am I missing? Maybe I should seek for a solution that doesn't involve GA? Or switch to a different analytics? Or track user's landing pages with cookies myself?

Comment: Doing it in Google Analytics, even if possible, may be painful. I would recommend using mixpanel.com.

Comment: Combining Google Analytics data with user identifiable data is a violation of Googles TOS (I would guess that's why they don't provide methods to do this :-) ). If your on php you could e.g. use Piwik (which provides limited functionality and scales very badly, but provides path info on a per user basis) or the aforementioned mixpanel which is specifically designed to collect personal data (which might cause legal problems in some countries).